# Replace Substring in a text file with arrays of strings using Sed

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace substring in a text file with some other substrings using `sed`
For example,

`sed 's/dogs chase/<bop> dogs chase <eop>/g; s/birds eat/<bop> birds eat <eop>'/g corpus.txt`

So instead of `dogs chase` in `corpus.txt`, I replace it with `<bop> dogs chase <eop>`, `birds eat` with `<bop> birds eat <eop>`.

Suppose I have all the substrings in  a textfile `sub.txt` and I want to use to replace the text in the corpus.txt file, is there a way I can have my command to work
.e.g.

```
dogs chase
birds eat
chase birds
chase cat
```

`sed 's/dogs chase/<bop> dogs chase <eop>/g; s/chase birds/<bop> chase birds <eop>/g; s/chase cat/<bop> chase cat <eop>/g; s/birds eat/<bop> birds eat <eop>'/g corpus.txt`

The `sed` command would replace `dogs chase` with `<bop> dogs chase <eop>`, `birds eat` with `<bop> birds eat </eop>`, `chase birds` with `<bop> chase birds <eop>`, `chase cat` and `<bop> chase cat <eop>`. The hand crafted command would be difficult to write if the `sub.txt` contains 100s of the substring.

Note the corpus.txt file

```
dogs chase cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
dogs chase birds
cats chase birds , birds eat grains
dogs chase the cats
the birds chirp
```

The desired output:

```
<bop> dogs chase <eop> cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
<bop> dogs chase <eop> birds 
cats <bop> chase birds <eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
<bop> dogs chase <eop> the cats
the birds chirp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed and bash:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|&|<bop> & <eop>|g/' sub.txt) corpus.txt
```

Output:

```
<bop> dogs chase <eop> cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
<bop> dogs chase <eop> birds
cats <bop> chase birds <eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
<bop> dogs chase <eop> the cats
the birds chirp
```

Comment: If I change the order of the `sub.txt` with `chase cat` coming first. It changes the output with the first line becoming `dogs <bop> chase cat<eop>s around`. Do you think I can do something to prevent such from happening? As what I am trying to do is a kind of bi-gram matching.

Comment: This might help. `\b` marks a word boundary: `sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|\\b&\\b|<bop> & <eop>|g/' sub.txt) corpus.txt`

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, I'm sorry I'm disturbing you again. I added `chase birds .` to `sub.txt` and  the 5th line in the `corpus.txt` becomes `cats <bop> <bop> chase birds . <eop>eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains` which is not suppose to be so. What can I do?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question with these requirements.